# React redux typescript: connect has missing type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get a react-redux app going with typescript, but I keep circling around the same error. The following code compiles and produces expected result

```
// State definition
interface HelloWorldState {
    clickCount: number
}
interface AppState extends HelloWorldState {}


// Props definitions
interface HelloWorldProps {
    count: number
}


// Actions
const CLICK = 'CLICK';
const click = () => {return {type:CLICK}};


// Reducers
function clickCount(state:number = 0, action:Action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case CLICK:
            return state + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
    clickCount
});


// Store
let store = createStore(rootReducer);


// Components
class HelloWorld extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Hello world "{this.props.count}"</div>
    }

    handleClick() {
        store.dispatch(click())
    }
}


// Container components
const mapStateToProps = (state:AppState):HelloWorldState => {
    return Immutable.fromJS({
        count: state.clickCount
    })
};
const ConnectedHelloWorld = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(HelloWorld);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedHelloWorld/>
    </Provider>,
    container
);
```

Great! But I am using TypeScript, because I want to get type checks at compile time. The most important thing to type check is state and props. So instead of `class HelloWorld extends React.Component<any, any>`, I want to do `class HelloWorld extends React.Component<HelloWorldProps, any>`. When I do this, however, I get the following compile error from the call to `render`

```
TS2324:Property 'count' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<HelloWorld> & HelloWorldProps & { children?: React...'.
```

I don't really understand why. `count` **IS** present in the `HelloWordProps` definition, and it is provided by the reducer, so I should be fine, right? Similar questions has suggested that it is an inference problem, and that I should declare the type of the call to `connect`, but I can't seem to find out how

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reacttsx",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "flux": "^3.1.2",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "registry:npm/flux#2.1.1+20160601175240",
    "immutable": "registry:npm/immutable#3.7.6+20160411060006",
    "react": "registry:npm/react#15.0.1+20170104200836",
    "react-dom": "registry:npm/react-dom#15.0.1+20160826174104",
    "react-redux": "registry:npm/react-redux#4.4.0+20160614222153",
    "redux-logger": "registry:dt/redux-logger#2.6.0+20160726205300",
    "redux-thunk": "registry:npm/redux-thunk#2.0.0+20160525185520"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160726191732",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "registry:dt/isomorphic-fetch#0.0.0+20170120045107",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20170104155652",
    "redux": "registry:dt/redux#3.5.2+20160703092728",
    "redux-thunk": "registry:dt/redux-thunk#2.1.0+20160703120921"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since it was complaining that `count` was missing, I tried updating to

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedHelloWorld count={0}/>
    </Provider>,
    container
);
```

This solves the issue. So the issue is that the compiler doesn't know that the `Provider` is providing the count. Provider uses the store. The store should have the `clickCount` value which is mapped to `count` by the container component.

I noticed I'd forgotten an initial state for the store. So even if the types had checked out, the state would be empty. I updated it to

```
// Store
let initialState:AppState = {clickCount: 0};
let store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

Now I am certain that `clickCount` is set properly in the store. So I'd expect the `mapStateToProps` function to take the `AppState` and return the `HelloWorldProps` as specified, and then the `Provider` should provide the count value. This is true, but the compiler does not see it.

So how to remedy that?

Comment: Do you get this error even if you only do the simple `HelloWorld` class? (that is, without the redux) Because it works for me. Also, what version of react are you using?

Comment: By the simple one, you mean `HelloWorld extends React.Component<any, any>`? Yes, that works always, because the types of its state and props are `any`. So no error there.

Comment: No, by simple I mean having only `class HelloWorld extends React.Component<HelloWorldProps, any>` without the redux stuff. For me that compiles just fine. What version of react/typescript are you using?

Comment: I updated the question. You are correct, the issue is from redux or react-redux

Comment: You can find an example of a connect here: https://github.com/Black-Monolith/LightCycle/blob/master/app/containers/Counter.tsx.
It separates the current component from the container file where we `connect()` the component to the store.
We also export `MappedProps` type to be able to use it as props type in the component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This how I do it in a Typescript Redux App (adjusted to your code but not tested)

**edited with comment below**

1. type `connect` with props for the Connected Component (`ConnectedHelloWorldProps`)

   ```
   const ConnectedHelloWorld:React.ComponentClass<ConnectedHelloWorldProps>  = 
       connect<any,any,HelloWorldProps>(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld)

   interface ConnectedHelloWorldProps { }

   interface HelloWorldProps extends ConnectedHelloWorldProps {
       count: number
       ....
   }
   ```
2. use the connected component and its `ConnectedHelloWorldProps` props in the `Provider`

   ```
   <Provider store={store}>
       <ConnectedHelloWorld/>
   </Provider>
   ```

Note: this works fine with these typings

```
"@types/react": "^0.14.52",
"@types/react-dom": "^0.14.19",
"@types/react-redux": "^4.4.35",
"@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.32",
```

`ConnectedHellowWorldProps` is not really needed here, since it is an empty interface, but in a real world scenario it is likely to contain a few props.

The basic principle is this: `ConnectedHelloWorldProps` contain what needs to be passed at the Provider level. In `mapStateToProps` and/or `mapDispatchToProps`, enrich the actual Component `HelloWorldProps` with whatever is needed

Redux Typescript typings are a beast but what is shown above should be sufficient.

```
export declare function connect<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>(
mapStateToProps: FuncOrSelf<MapStateToProps<TStateProps, TOwnProps>>,
 mapDispatchToProps?: FuncOrSelf<MapDispatchToPropsFunction<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps> | MapDispatchToPropsObject>): ComponentDecorator<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;


 interface ComponentDecorator<TOriginalProps, TOwnProps> {
    (component: ComponentClass<TOriginalProps> | StatelessComponent<TOriginalProps>): ComponentClass<TOwnProps>;
 }
```

Comment: will that let you define the `<ConnectedHelloWorld />` component without props? They should be provided by the provider after all? When I do `<ConnectedHelloWorld count={null} />`, the compiler accepts it, and when I run it, I see that the provider provides the 0 from the initial state properly

Comment: Yes. Do not define the `count` property in `ConnectedHelloWorldProps` and assign it to `0` or `state.clickCount` in `mapStateToProp()`

Comment: Your call to connect gives me `error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: We probably do not have the exact same typings. I have edited the answer with the typings I use

Comment: How do you manage typings? I install `npm install typings` and then use `node_modules/.bin/typings install ...` to fetch the typings. But you seem to have newer version than I, so how did you get them?

Comment: If you use last version of TypeScript you can use NPM to install typings through `@types` : 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed. Nice that we can just use npm now. Really simplifies things.

Comment: if I write directly `export default connect<any,any,HelloWorldProps>(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld)`, I have the error saying that I should declare the `count` property. However if I write `export default connect<any,any,HelloWorldProps>(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld) as ComponentClass<ConnectedHelloWorldProps>` it works well, why do we need to explicitly saying that we are returning the type  `ComponentClass<ConnectedHelloWorldProps>` ?

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was passing null for the mapDispatchToProps param in the connect function like this since I wasn't using dispatch for this component:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MainLayout);
```

Changing it to just omit the mapDispatchToProps param fixed it for me

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainLayout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `HelloWorldState` is defined like this

```
interface HelloWorldState {
  clickCount: number
}
```

And the props you want to return from `mapStateToProps` are

```
{ 
  count: state.clickCount
}
```

But you override the return-type as `HelloWorldState`, so the return type does not contain `count` but `clickCount`.

---

## `fromJS` breaks type safety

`ImmutableJS.fromJS` works pretty bad with TypeScript type inference:

```
const state = Immutable.fromJS({
  count: 0
})
```

Here `state` is of type `any` so you don't have any error when assigning it as a return value of type `HelloWorldState`.

---

## `mapStateToProps` should return a simple object

`mapStateToProps` can return a simple object, as you won't directly edit this state from the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): HelloWorldState => {
  return {
    count: state.clickCount
  }
}
```

Here you will have the error you did not have when using ImmutableJS, telling you that you cannot assign `{ count: number }` to `{ clickCount: number }`.

So just remove the return type, and type-inference will do the job, or add the correct type.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
  return {
    count: state.clickCount
  }
}
```

---

## Statically-typed tree structural-sharing with Monolite

I also recommend you to use [**Monolite**](https://github.com/kube/monolite) which is a simple set of functions written in TypeScript and designed to be used with Redux states.

It allows you to also define your state with simple JavaScript objects, and to make updates on the state through simple functions.

```
import { set } from 'monolite'

const state = {
  clickCount: 0
}

const newState = set(state, _ => _.clickCount)(value => value + 1)
```

---

**P.S.** I'm the author of Monolite

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while writing a component class with connect(). In my case, there was a circular dependency in the props

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {/* return something here */}
const mapStateToProps = (state: IState, ownProps: AllProps) => {/* return something here */}
type AllProps = {
someExtraProp: string;
} & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
```

As you can see this caused a circular type dependency between AllProps and mapStateToProps. I segregated out the OwnProps code and it looks like this now:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {/* return something here */}
const mapStateToProps = (state: IState, ownProps: OwnProps) => {/* return something here */}
const OwnProps = {
someExtraProp: string;
};
type AllProps = OwnProps & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
```

Now, the connect call doesn't throw any type errors. Hopefully this helps someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you!