# React Redux with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am learning react and typescript with redux. I have a child component like this:

```
import ...
interface MainTestProps {
   loadData: () => () => void,
   students: StudentsModel[],
   state: string,
   errorMessage?:string
}

interface MainTestState {
}

class MainTest extends React.Component<MainTestProps,MainTestState>{

constructor(props: MainTestProps, state: MainTestState){
    super(props,state);

}

.... rest of component
const mapStateToProps = (state:AppState, ownProps: MainTestProps)=> {
    return {
      students: [],
      state: 'INIT',
      errorMessage:''
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
   return {
       loadData: () => dispatch(actionFetchStudents())
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (MainTest);
```

Why if I call this component   i receive the error Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly & MainTestProps>': loadData, students, state ts(2739). I mean I do not want to pass properties, I am using redux!!! Is there a bug in the typescript redux library or why I have to pass data or is my declaration of mapStateToProps wrong an I have to obmit the parameter ownProps.

Thank you all
Arnold

Comment: possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808408/react-redux-typescript-connect-has-missing-type-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808408/react-redux-typescript-connect-has-missing-type-error)

Answer (score 0):

Could you show how you are calling this `MainTest` component? Since you are only adding `loadData` through Redux, the other parameters `students` and `state` should still be passed to the component as a prop. The `errorMessage` prop is optional, so the transpiler does not complain about it.

The reason the transpiler complains about the `loadData` prop, is most likely because the type you supply in `MainTestProps` does not correspond to the type of the `loadData` function. I can only guess, since I don't have the actual implementation of `actionFetchStudents`, but it seems reasonable the type of `loadData` should be `loadData: () => void;`, instead of `loadData: () => () => void;`.

See if that works, otherwise please provide the implementations of `actionFetchStudents` and the function where you call `MainTest`.

Answer (score -1):

```
interface State {}

interface OwnProps {}

interface DispatchProps {
    login: () => void;
}

interface StateProps {
    isFetching: boolean;
    accessToken: string;
}

type Props = StateProps & OwnProps & DispatchProps;

const ExampleTH = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
```

You can use something like this,this wirks with react 16.8.4